# Converting NVARCHAR(255) to DATE

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012, type-conversion

I'm trying to transfer some old SQL Server data using Excel into SQL Server. It seems that `Import/Export Data` application automatically sets most data columns to `NVARCHAR(255)`. Problem I have, is one of my columns is supposed to be a `DATE` type, but all data in it looks like this `18.08.2000 14:48:15`.

So, when I try to use this query:

```
SELECT CONVERT(Date, DATE_TIME,  113)
FROM someTable
```

I get this error:

> Msg 9807, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   The input character string does not follow style 113, either change the input character string or use a different style.

None of the `[styles]` from [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) are working in my case.

Any advise or help is greatly appreciated.

**SOLVED:**

```
UPDATE myTable
SET columnName = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255),CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, columnName,105))
ALTER TABLE myTable
ALTER COLUMN columnName SMALLDATETIME
```

Comment: So nobody has to guess, could you specify your version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, if it will ever become useful to anyone, this is the exact code that changes datatype NVARCHAR to DATETIME:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET columnName = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255),CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, columnName,105))
ALTER TABLE myTable
ALTER COLUMN columnName SMALLDATETIME
```

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can tell - style no. 103 (*British/French*) should work - no?

```
DECLARE @input NVARCHAR(255)

SET @input = '18.08.2000 14:48:15'

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, @input, 103)
```

Gives me the output of:

```
2000-08-18 14:48:15.000
```

which seems pretty reasonable, no??

Comment: Im sorry if Im not clear. What Im trying to do is change column datatype from NVARCHAR(255) to DATE or DATETIME in MS-SQL database. I guess 103 will work, but when I try to use this code, and replace `SET @input = '18.08.2000 14:48:15'` with `SET @INPUT = 'DATE_TIME'` I still get the same error.

Comment: You need to do `SET @INPUT = DATE_TIME` (without the single quotes! Otherwise you're setting the `@input` variable to `DATE_TIME` as a value - and that **of course** doesn't convert to a `datetime` ....

Comment: Thank you it works. But I still wonder why is it "only" style 103 that  works?

Comment: Why is output `yyyy-mm-dd` if output format is `103`? If I have an `dd-mm-yyyy` input format in `varchar` and need the same format for my output, how can I do it?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using SQL Server 2012, try:

```
PARSE(Date AS datetime USING 'en-GB')
```

Or if that doesn't work, try:

```
PARSE(Date AS datetime USING 'Et-EE')
```

The Estonian culture specifically uses '.' as a date separator (`d.MM.yyyy H:mm:ss`) so it should work.

(Both seem to work fine on SQL Fiddle)

Comment: Works perfectly on SQL Server 2016.