# Alter column from NVARCHAR to NBINARY

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I accidentally created a column with the wrong type `NVARCHAR` (for storing password salts) and I want to convert it to `NVARBINARY`.

I tried

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName]
    ALTER COLUMN [ColumnName] [varbinary] (20) NOT NULL
GO
```

but it says

> *Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.*

Is there a way to do that? `CONVERT` seems to be for expressions only, not for alterations.

Comment: You might have better luck adding a new column of the correct type, copying/converting the data from old to new column, and then removing the old column.

Comment: is that column already contains value?

Comment: Here is a link to the covert function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175509(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: The column already contains values, yes. I need to create an upgrade script, not a create script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way by altering will be someting like:

```
Create Table a (id int,blb Nvarchar(10))


insert into a Values
(1,'Test'),
(2,N'Test2');

BEGIN Transaction
ALTER TABLE a
ADD blb_New [varbinary] (20) NULL
GO

UPDATE a
SET blb_new = CAST(blb AS varbinary(20))
GO

ALTER TABLE a
DROP COLUMN blb
GO

EXEC sp_rename 'a.blb_new', 'blb', 'COLUMN'
GO
COMMIT Transaction


Select *,CAST(blb as Nvarchar(20)) from a

Drop Table a
```

Comment: Great solution. Had something along those lines in mind, but I thought there might be something easier. Thanks!

Comment: everything between (including) the first `ALTER TABLE` and the `sp_rename` needs to be executed inside a transaction, to lock other users out. If there is concurrent traffic and you don't use a transaction you will most likely end up with data loss.

Answer (score 0):

You may first convert all the values from NVARCHAR to NVARBINARY in the same column.
After converting all the values use Alter table

You may refer the following link:
[Converting NVARCHAR(255) to DATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13124944/converting-nvarchar255-to-date)

Comment: You can Do that "Update a set blb=cast(blb as varbinary(10))"
but you wont't able to do that "Alter Table a Alter Column blb varbinary(10)" nevertheless. The examle you are referencing is not blocking because implicit conversion is not possible, but why the values containt can not be convertet.