# Change column from VARCHAR(MAX) to VARBINARY(MAX)

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which has a `VARCHAR(MAX)` column, and I need to change it to `VARBINARY(MAX)`.

I tried using the command

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ALTER COLUMN ColumnName VARBINARY(MAX)
```

but I got the error

> *Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>
>   Implicit conversion from data type varchar(max) to varbinary(max) is not allowed.
>
>   Use the CONVERT function to run this query.*

The table has no data, so I can't understand why it's complaining about data conversion.

Comment: if you have the data in the table then you cannot change datatype like that.because existing data will not allow you to do that.

Comment: As I said, the table has no data.

Comment: sorry,missed the last line

Comment: If you have no data, you can drop the column and create it with its new type.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305224/alter-column-from-nvarchar-to-nbinary/14305756#14305756

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You cannot perform this conversion using an `ALTER TABLE` statement since [converting from `varchar(max)` to `varbinary(max)` requires an explicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). So you should follow these steps to alter your table:

1. Alter table with new column of `VARBINARY(MAX)`
2. If you have existing data in the `VARCHAR(MAX)` column, use update statement to add the data to the `VARBINARY` column
3. Alter table to drop the `VARCHAR(MAX)` column
4. Rename `varbinary` column to `varchar` name (per comment from [@Ben Thul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539445/change-column-from-varcharmax-to-varbinarymax#comment20281873_14539582))

Comment: 4. Rename varbinary column to varchar column's name.

Comment: I had to look this up, but if anyone else finds this. Use `EXEC sp_rename` to change a column's name.

Answer (score 3):

Convert `Varchar` to `Int` and then change `Int` to `Binary`.

Comment: With an empty table, this is fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: `ALTER TABLE studentlogins MODIFY password VARBINARY(255);`

Comment: MODIFY is a MySQL keyword. This topic is for (MS) SQL Server.

`Incorrect syntax near 'MODIFY'.`