# How to move data from nvarchar(max) column to varbinary(max) column in SQL server without changing the value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with column name Logo which has a datatype nvarchar(max) but the content is already in Base64 format. I want to move data from this column to another column which has a data type varbinary(max). If i use convert function it converts the logo Byte to varbinary which was actually in byte. How can i do this.
Such as in the Logo column which has nvarchar(max) data type i have this -

`'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFoAAABaCAYAAAA4qEECAAAACXBI......'`

and i want to move exactly the same value to another column which has a data type varbinary(max).

Thanx in advance

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "the content is already in Byte".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Base64 encoding in SQL Server 2005 T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082345/base64-encoding-in-sql-server-2005-t-sql)

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539445/change-column-from-varcharmax-to-varbinarymax

Comment: See the duplicate, it tells you how to convert Base64 in T-SQL. Also, a "sample" just means that -- you don't have to post the complete string, which makes the question unreadable :-P

Comment: This might help. During convert just use 1 which is important. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63743/converting-a-varchar-to-varbinary

Comment: @Pankaj_Dwivedi if i use 1 in convert function style paramter i got this error
'Error converting data type nvarchar to varbinary'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am reading between the lines here, but I *think* the OP is saying that have data in a `varchar` column that has values like `'0x1A23494947D324B'`. As a result something like `SELECT CONVERT(varbinary,'0x1234');` doesn't return what the OP expects (`0x307831323334`).

You need to use a style code here, to let SQL Server know that the value is already in a `varbinary` format:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varbinary(MAX),'0x1234',1);
```