# How to convert Nvarchar Value To time?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Here are my query:

```
 declare @t NVARCHAR ='06:05:03'
 select @t
```

How can I find answer in `timestamp`?

Comment: Have you tried cast as time?

Comment: I think this helps you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13124944/converting-nvarchar255-to-date

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @t NVARCHAR(10) ='06:05:03' 
DECLARE @con TIME = CONVERT (TIME , @t)

SELECT @con
```

Answer (score 0):

When length is not specified for NVARCHAR, default length is one. [Refer to MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

So, you have to give proper length for NVARCHAR. We are converting to time(0), assuming you dont want to have precisions for seconds.

```
DECLARE @t NVARCHAR(8) =N'06:05:03' 
SELECT cast(@t as time(0))
```