# How to Order by date when my Column is type String in Sql Server 2017 and C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2017

I am trying to order by date in my database but I can't because it gives me an error. I'm using SQL Server 2017.

I already read other articles about it but when I try it still gives me the same error.

My table name is "Ferramentas" and my column name is "DataCriacao". I tried this:

```
 Select * From Ferramentas order By CONVERT(date, Data_Criação,101) Desc
```

Also I tried:

```
 Select * From Ferramentas Order By Cast(Data_Criação As Date) Desc
```

The error is:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

In my database "Data_Criacao" the type is *nchar(20)*.

My date is something like "05th of December 2018"

I need this to my SQL server and C# code because I'm doing an APP and some datas are not in right formating and I can not change, I just can adapt my code to this.

Could you help me please?

Comment: Why *is* `Data_Criação` a `varchar` when you are storing date data in it? Also, your title says you are using SQL Server 2008, however, the text of your question says you are using "2013". There is no SQL Server 2013. What are you *really* using? What is the output of `PRINT @@VERSION;`?

Comment: Take a look at this . it might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13124944/converting-nvarchar255-to-date

Comment: Show us a sample of a few rows' worth of the text data in that column.  Also scan the column - are _any_ values in it invalid dates?

Comment: don't store dates as strings in the first place and you can avoid these kinds of issues. The `datetime` types exist for a reason

Comment: Did you try datetime instead of date eg:  `Cast(Data_Criação As DATETIME) Desc` ?

Comment: @Larnu I 'm sorry the correct version is SQL Server 2017

Comment: @ADyson the problem is that I didn't create this database. I know this would be more easy if the type was "date" but at the moment, i have a lot of register and now I can't drop the table

Comment: Then why did you state 2008 in your title? Anyway, what is the output of `SELECT [Data_Criação] FROM dbo.Ferramentas WHERE TRY_CONVERT(date,[Data_Criação]) IS NULL;`. **Put the results in your question, as `text`, and comment that you have added them.**

Comment: Agreed, we need to see a sample of the raw data which would cause the error to occur.

Comment: I put the error  there. When I tried in both solution gave me  *Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string*

Comment: That looks like _style_ 103, have you tried `Select * From Ferramentas order By CONVERT(date, Data_Criação,103) Desc` ?

Comment: But you haven't posted any sample data that replicates the issue @BráulioJoelson. `SELECT CONVERT(date,'05/12/2018');` does not produce an error.

Comment: @AlexLemesios I tried your solution but give me the same error

Comment: @BráulioJoelson the *problem* is using the wrong type - varchar instead of date. If applications stored dates using different formats in the table *all* attempts at parsing will fail. Those that succeed can't be trusted - Is 5/12 May 12 or December 5? You should check your data for day values above 13. Do you have a 5/13, 13/5 or both? Which applications wrote each one?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i tried now, give to me the same error

Comment: @BráulioJoelson there's no magic solution for bad data. Find days above 13 first, to discover what the real formats are. Check for mixed up formats. If you do have mixed formats you'll have to discover which format is used in the *non*failing cases

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the aplication is C# I 'm add my date with "dataPicker"

Comment: Can't you do `Select TOP(10) Data_Criação From Ferramentas` and paste the result here, preferable with some rows that can't be converted ?

Comment: @BráulioJoelson you aren't. Even if you used the DateTime value returned by `DatePicker.Value` you format it as as a string using *the client's locale* and storing that string in the database instead of the real `DateTime` value. If even a single client had a different locale, the result will be mixed up and lost data. It's common for developers to use US formats on their machines even though their users don't

Comment: @BráulioJoelson the correct way, shown in all tutorials, is to take the `DateTime` value offered by the `Value` property, use a parameterized query (ie no string concatenation) and pass it as a `date` or `datetime` parameter, and finally store it in a `date` field

Comment: It would be helpful to see what format the data is in. **Be sure to include some dates from after 12th of the month.**

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos to do what you advised I would have to drop the table and at the moment I can't do date. I'm a new programmer and I see that this database has errors and I'm trying to fix because I didn't start to develop the database

Comment: OK, now your question makes even less sense. Are you saying the data in the database isn't like `05/12/2018` but is in fact like `05th of December 2018`?

Comment: @BráulioJoelson the error is the field type and data access code. Anything else just covers things up. BTW applying `convert` or `cast` to that field means you can't use any indexes on it and the server will have to scan the entire table to find matching values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear whether you want 103 or 101 for the format.  Let's assume your date is mm/dd/yyyy.

The best guess is that not all dates are in that format.  So, use `try_convert()`:

```
order By try_convert(date, Data_Criação, 101) desc
```

To find the offending values, write a query such as:

```
select Data_Criação
from Ferramentas
where try_convert(date, Data_Criação, 101) is null;
```

Along the way, think about how to fix your data model so values are stored using the correct types.

Comment: Considering the value is `05/12/2018` I'd guess it's `dd/MM/yyyy` (as that would be today's date).

Comment: @Larnu What about the *applications* that store dates in such a haphazard way? I suspect Gordon is right and the formats are mixed up making it impossible to find the real dates.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos most likely, I was just making the assumption on  the **one** sample row the OP has given us; after multiple requests for sample data that replicates the issue...

Comment: select Data_Criação
     from Ferramentas
     where try_convert(date, Data_Criação, 103) desc 

this resolve my case

Comment: @BráulioJoelson that's because it *discards* any values that don't match the pattern and returns `NULL`. You still have to find what those values are, why they are there and what to do about them

Comment: I don't know why my question is unuseful, why someone give to me -1?.
I had doubt and I try my best to specify what I wanted and I am just new making programs. this is not fair, now i can't ask more questions about