# SQL Server : convert nvarchar to date

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to convert a string column of datatype `nvarchar` which looks like DD.MM.YYYY to `Date` type.

I need the simplest `Date` type (no need for clock time) so I can treat this column as a date.

Thanks!

Edit: I tried what all recommended but it doesn't work

```
UPDATE [test3]
SET [column3] = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, [column2], 105))

ALTER TABLE [test3]
ALTER COLUMN [column3] SMALLDATETIME
```

Error:

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: What search terms did you use in Google when you were researching how to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting NVARCHAR(255) to DATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13124944/converting-nvarchar255-to-date)

Comment: Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) and pick the number that would convert to your favorite format.  The german 104 seems promissing?

Comment: i tried CONVERT and CAST , either wont work. also, the date format is not matter, only the option to treat this column as a date, so i can search for specific date or period

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert to dd.mm.yyyy then you can use like below:

```
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 104)
```

but in your case you can just convert nvarchar to date as below:

```
select convert(date, yourdate)
```

Comment: You still need to pass the style parameter to eliminate regional ambiguity. For example (I'm in the US):

SELECT CONVERT(DATE,'03.12.2019') returns '2019-03-12'

whereas SELECT CONVERT(DATE,'03.12.2019',104) returns '2019-12-03'

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edits and what you said you wanted, you appear to be doing things a bit out of order and also, I'm not sure why you used SMALLDATETIME when you just wanted DATE, but OK.

I'm assuming your table has [column2] of type VARCHAR with data that looks like DD.MM.YYYY that you wish to treat as a date rather than string.

First, create a column to hold date information:

```
ALTER TABLE [test3] ADD [column3] DATE
```

Then you can populate the new column by converting your string data:

```
UPDATE [test3] SET [column3] = CONVERT(DATE, [column2], 104)
```

Also, the format absolutely matters because in the US '03.12.2019' will be converted to March 12 rather than December 3. You can make a real mess if you assume your server's locale settings are correct.

Comment: thank for help, it's exactly what i did (BTW, column2 is Nvarchar) still error: 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.' ; i tried Date tye and also smallDateTime.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a problem with converting the data in your column?
Then first discover and correct the data that's wrong, or in an unexpected format.

To find them, you could make use of [TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql)
Which does the same as a normal [CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql).
But instead of throwing errors, a `TRY_CONVERT` will simply output NULL if the conversion fails.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [column2], [column3]
FROM [test3]
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(DATE, [column2], 104) IS NULL
  AND [column2] IS NOT NULL;
```

Once you found the troublemakers in your data, and corrected them?
Then the update should work.

```
UPDATE [test3]
SET [column3] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATE, [column2], 104), 23);
```

After that the type of column3 can be changed.

```
ALTER TABLE [test3]
  ALTER COLUMN [column3] DATE;
```

Or first set all the column3 to NULL, then do the type change, then update from column2.

```
UPDATE [test3]
SET [column3] = NULL;
WHERE [column3] IS NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE [test3]
  ALTER COLUMN [column3] DATE;

UPDATE [test3]
SET [column3] = CONVERT(DATE, [column2], 104);
WHERE [column2] IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: thank you!! [test3] is just small test table i created to try the process before the real big table. i accidentally hade 30.02 which it can not be converted. now it's work properly! gratitude!

Comment: Great!  Yeah, sometimes assumption about data can cause troubles.  Btw,  to alter the column3 there was another option.  First update all of column3 to NULL, alter the type of column3, THEN do the update from column2.

Answer (score 0):

#### If you get "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string" error

Reason why you get this error is:

If you do this:

```
select convert (date, '2021-12-30', 23) as datum
```

since 23 is for `yyyy-mm-dd` format, like: 2006-12-30 It will work ok.

But if you do this:

```
select convert (date, '2021-12-30', 104) as datum
```

Since 104 is for `dd.mm.yyyy` format, like  30.12.2006 you will get error:

> [S0001][241] Line 1: Conversion failed when converting date and/or
> time from character string.