# How to write a query to convert nvarchar to date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a single column that contains date and string values. How to write a query to convert a string to date value?

Table `usercomment`:

```
comment
----------
02/22/2020
03/22/2020
Nochange
04/22/2020
userreviw
```

Desired output:

```
comment
-----------
2020-02-22
2020-03-22
Nochange
2020-04-22
userreviw
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting NVARCHAR(255) to DATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13124944/converting-nvarchar255-to-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select CASE 
         ISDATE(myColumn) WHEN 1 THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(10), CONVERT(datetime, myColumn, 101), 120)
         ELSE myColumn 
       end
From myTable
```

Comment: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Updated the code to add the conversion output parameter.

Comment: Realized we have to convert to varchar so since the other values are varchar.

Comment: Was able to sit down at SSMS finally and just realized the other answer was accepted.  Correct mine and tested just so that it is a working select block now.  Stole the conversion to datetime first, then converting to an nvarchar(10) to get the correct date format.

Comment: Thanks big! It's working now. Final requirement is write a query which comment less than 2 days yes other than no.    comment           iscomment_2days
-----------
2020-05-29             Y
2020-05-31             N
Nochange               N
2020-04-29             Y
userreviw              N

Answer (score 4):

Try using `TRY_CONVERT`:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(TRY_CONVERT(varchar(10),
                         TRY_CONVERT(datetime, col, 101),
                         120), col) AS col_as_date
FROM yourTable;
```

The format mask 101 in the first call to `TRY_CONVERT` corresponds to the date format `mm/dd/yyyy`, which matches your data, when it has a valid date.  For invalid values, such as `comment`, `TRY_CONVERT` will return `NULL`.  Then, we call `TRY_CONVERT` with mask 120 to generate text dates in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`.